# Typescript version of a config.js file

Tags: node.js, typescript

Typically I'll have a config.js file that looks something like this:

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  secret: "sdlfjlsdjkflsdjfsdjflsdjf",
  terminal_id: '39493843',
  transaction_key: 'asdfsldkfjdslkfjsdl'
};
```

And I'll use it like this:

**index.js**

```
const config = require('./config');
console.log(config.secret);
```

What is the typescript way of doing this? What does the config.ts file look like and how do I import it in the index.ts file?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little closer to your original design would be this:

**config.ts**

```
export default {
  secret: "sdlfjlsdjkflsdjfsdjflsdjf",
  terminal_id: '39493843',
  transaction_key: 'asdfsldkfjdslkfjsdl'
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import config from './config';
console.log(config.secret);
```

You don't need to declare the types of your config properties, typescript will infer that from the constants.  You still get all the type checking goodness and intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Arpit Solanki's comment, I've done this:

**config.ts**

```
export const secret: string = 'sdlfjlsdjkflsdjfsdjflsdjf';
export const terminal_id: string = '39493843',
export const transaction_key: string = 'asdfsldkfjdslkfjsdl';
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as config from './config';
console.log(config.secret);
```